# Panda dataframe print to console without column names

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe like:

```
         0       1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8  class
0   0.4444  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.1111  0.0000  0.2222  0.0000  0.0000      0
1   0.4444  0.3333  0.3333  0.4444  0.6667  1.0000  0.2222  0.1111  0.0000      0
2   0.2222  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.1111  0.1111  0.2222  0.0000  0.0000      0
```

All I want this to be printed on console without newline and without column names:

```
0.4444,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.1111,0.0000,0.2222,0.0000,0.0000,0
0.4444,0.3333,0.3333,0.4444,0.6667,1.0000,0.2222,0.1111,0.0000,0
0.2222,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.1111,0.1111,0.2222,0.0000,0.0000,0
..
```

There are 360 rows in total.

I am new to Pandas and cannot figure out how to achieve this. I tried converting pandas to numpy array, to list and tried printing with `print(data, end='')` but none worked for me.

### Solved:

If any one comes across similar problem ,
solved using `df_to_csv` and `sys.stdout`:
`df.to_csv(sys.stdout, header=False, index=False, float_format='%.4f')`

Answer (score 6):

```
df.to_string(index=False, header=False)
```

This says, convert the dataframe to a string, but without the index labels and without the column (header) labels.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to do this and I can found this code:

```
def print_df(df):
   # This code delete index and columns names
   df_ = df.copy()
   df_.columns = ['', '', '', '']
   df_.index = ['' for _ in range(len(df))]
   print(df_)

print_df(df)
```

Other way that I found, but without right spaces between values for column format:

```
[print(*row, sep=', ') for row in df.values.tolist()];
```

Comment: the list comprehension works but also prints "," after the last value , which is not required

Comment: I edit the list comprehension to remove the last ','

Comment: solved this problem using df.to_csv(sys.stdout,header=False,index=False,float_format='%.4f')

Answer (score 1):

##### Q: How print pandas dataframe without columns

##### A:

```py
print('\n'.join(df.to_string(index = False).split('\n')[1:]))
```

##### Explanation:

```py
dfstr   = df.to_string(index = False) # Make str, possibly remove index
dfrows  = dfstr.split('\n')           # split on rows
dfprint = dfrows[1:]                  # Do not print row 0 (columns)
dfp     = '\n'.join(dfprint)          # Create a single string again
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `print` values in loop with `f-string`s for 3 digits after decimal with `join`:

```
for x in df.values:
    print (','.join(f'{y:.4f}' for y in x))

0.4444,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.1111,0.0000,0.2222,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000
0.4444,0.3333,0.3333,0.4444,0.6667,1.0000,0.2222,0.1111,0.0000,0.0000
0.2222,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.1111,0.1111,0.2222,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000
```

If want no newline get one row of data:

```
for x in df.values:
    print (','.join(f'{y:.4f}' for y in x), end='')

0.4444,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.1111,0.0000,0.2222,0.0000,0.0000,0.00000.4444,0.3333,0.3333,0.4444,0.6667,1.0000,0.2222,0.1111,0.0000,0.00000.2222,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.1111,0.1111,0.2222,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000
```

Comment: @Jerzrael- you are missing a point the last value should not be .4f , its integer and will be 0 or 1. And it should be printed like rows in console even though there is no new line. I have already tried similar solution (no newline) , it didn't pass on auto checking

Comment: @ashim So problem is only last value per rows need integer?  Because not understan no newline. Because if use newline by `end=''`, it join each row together like my last solution. I am confused, because your expected output has newline, because each row is in separate row. Can you explain more what mean no newline?

Comment: @jezral: there should be no new line after the last row, i solved the problem using df.to_csv and sys.stdout