# How do I remove header row from a dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, header

```
       0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9  event
0  False   True  False   True   True  False   True   True   True  False      1
1  False   True  False   True   True   True   True   True  False  False      2
2   True   True  False  False  False   True  False  False   True  False      0
3   True   True   True   True  False  False   True   True   True  False      2
4   True  False   True  False  False  False   True   True   True   True      0
5   True  False   True  False  False  False   True  False   True   True      1
```

I have to remove 0 to event

I expect something like this

```
0  False   True  False   True   True  False   True   True   True  False      
1  False   True  False   True   True   True   True   True  False  False      
2   True   True  False  False  False   True  False  False   True  False      
3   True   True   True   True  False  False   True   True   True  False      
4   True  False   True  False  False  False   True   True   True   True      
5   True  False   True  False  False  False   True  False   True   True
```

Comment: You cannot - dataframe have column names, that is what makes a dataframe a dataframe. If you like, you could probably transform the data into a 2-dimensional numpy array, but really - what are you doing? Why do you want a dataframe without column names?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? [Panda dataframe print to console without column names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61133341/13843268).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Panda dataframe print to console without column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61133341/panda-dataframe-print-to-console-without-column-names)

Answer (score 1):

It makes no sense to delete column names  - how would you refer to the columns. But you can DISPLAY without column names:

```
print(df.to_string(header=False))
```

to_string actually produces a formatted string which can be re-formatted if required.